# Order of parameter evaluation of function call in GCC

Tags: c, operator-precedence

When I googled this I always got threads about order of evaluation in general stating order of evaluation is unspecified.

I know the parameter evaluation order is unspecified in `C` in general.

**My question is parameter evaluation order in `gcc`, left to right or right to left ?**

Any links to resources would also be appreciated...

**EDIT:** Removing ambiguity in the question

Well, I'm talking about the situation when

```
       foo(1+2,2+3,4+9)
```

which is first evaluated?

is it `1+2` or `4+9`... like wise..

**Can we come to a declaration by just compiling this in one gcc compiler....? or is it different across different gcc versions also?**

Comment: Probably not guaranteed to be either, or otherwise deterministic.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: this reference is all written for Order of evaluation http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @FAST I'm talking about C, you mean g++ and gcc do same?

Comment: @pinkpanther The C version of evaluation rules is very similar: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

Comment: @Cubbi does it not vary across implementations?

Comment: @pinkpanther it varies *within* implementations - changing platform, version, compilation flags, unrelated code before or after this expression, anything can change the order. GCC is no exception.

Comment: @Cubbi is there a chance that our code affects the order in that case....probably compiler choose the different order if some conditions occur... do you mean that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are really asking `foo(f1(), f2(), f3())` - which is more interesting than `foo(1+2, 3+4, 5+6)`, since adding 1+2 and 3+4 won't have effect whether it is done first or last or in a random order.

Now, unfortunately, you can not rely on `f1()` and `f2()` and `f3()` being called in any particular order - as long as each function is called ONCE, it's fine for the order to be any order:

```
   f1, f2, f3
   f1, f3, f2
   f2, f3, f1
   f2, f1, f3
   f3, f2, f1
   f3, f1, f2
```

(that covers all the permutations for three parameters).

It is entirely up to the compiler which it "thinks is best".

I wrote some code a long time back, and ran into this particular problem - I had something along the lines of:

```
char foo(char a, char b)
 ... 
 if (a =! 'x')
   foo(fgetc(f), foo(fgetc(f))); 
 ...
```

Since I expected the FIRST (left) `fgetc()` to be called first, and the second `fgetc()`, I could get the right behaviour. And it worked fine on the school computer. Then I took the code home and tried using it on my home computer. And for some reason it didn't work right. It took me quite some time to figure out that `foo()` was just being called infinitely, because `a` was never `'x'`, which stops the recursion - because `'x'` would never appear in the second call.

That was using gcc on both machines, but one was a sparc (school computer) and the one at home was a x86 (386, running OS/2, that's how long ago).

The solution is to break it into several lines:

```
 char aa = fgetc(f);
 char bb = fgetc(f);
 foo(aa, foo(bb));
```

Comment: I'm wondering does architectural factors affect the design of the compiler in these kind of issues also.... and don't the designers/implementers of gcc makes the gcc standard available somewhere for these kind of questions?

Comment: Different things may play a part in this. For example, if f1() is inlined, it may affect which registers it needs, so it may benefit from being done before f2() and f3() are called, or vice versa. The C++ standard itself makes it clear that "it's up to the compiler, and it doesn't have to work the same way each time". [It probably does if you compile the same source code, with the same compiler settings, etc, but if you change optimization level, it may decide to shuffle it the other way around, because it now inlined f2(), and that changes register usage -> different order is better.

Comment: Dont you think ,its kind of undefined behaviour in first foo because fgetc(f) is twice .if it is ,this behaviour does not represent the right mechanism , but in second foo( solution) , behaviour is removed ,so its works same ,always from left to right.

Comment: The code I posted was much simplified vs. the actual code, but the undefined behaviour, comes from two different functions that have side-effects on the same resource - in this case the position being read in a file - and relying on those two functions being called in a particular order.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1(void){
    printf("In F1\n");
    return 0;
}

int f2(void){
    printf("In F2\n");
    return 0;
}
int f3(void ){
    printf("In F3\n");
    return 0;
}
void f4(int a,int b,int c){
    printf("In F4\n");
    return;
}


int main(){

f4(f1(),f2(),f3());

  getch();
return 0; 
}



output
----------
In F3
In F2
In F1
In F4


but for 
printf("%d..%d..%d",(f1(),f2(),f3()));

output
---------
In F1
In F2
In F3
0..0..0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're conflating two concepts:  1) order of parameter evaluation (in a function call), and order of argument pushing.  In the first, it is unspecified (implementation-dependent) what order parameters are evaluated before being passed to a function.  In the second, it depends on the calling convention for the function, with cdecl pushing arguments from right to left, and almost all other conventions (e.g., pascal) pushing from left to right.

Comment: well I'm takin about function call

Comment: then the most that can be said, or relied upon, is that order is undefined.  it may even change from one version of gcc to the next.

Comment: The order of evaluation is *unspecified*, not undefined; there is a difference.  As long as no more than one expression has a side effect on a given object, the behavior is well-defined.  `foo(i++,j++,k++)` has well-defined behavior, even though the order in which `i`, `j`, and `k` are evaluated and updated is not specified.  `foo(i++,i++,i++)`, OTOH, invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnBode Yes, appreciate the precise language.

Comment: @JohnBode your comment is an eye opener of some sort

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++, which is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but the function call to f3 may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time.

Comment: I'm talking about c and I think you got my question wrong....or I framed my question wrong see my edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

In C, Parameter passing Mechanism is stack based 
means
it uses the stack (known as: Function Stack frame) to store the parameters and hence the order is Right because Stack is LIFO .that was up to my understandings .
Kindly have a look at this link ,it will explain you more ,i hope u may find some thing useful
http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs427/2012a/resources/Chapter_05.pdf

*pg#55* ,*5.2.3 Parameter Passing Mechanisms*

Comment: are you wish fully making posts as community wiki? or accidental or unknowingly? :)

Comment: Totally unknowingly....i read about it on meta stack ...and i am more confused now

Comment: community answers doesn't earn you repuation on upvotes/accepts/downvotes... any body can edit them

Comment: coming to the actual question, though your reasoning is good, that's not the reality...... see @MatsPetersson answer on the issue

Comment: Thanks, it is a new feature on my profile. So im lucky ,you told me

Answer (score 0):

```
// according to my tests: left to right for clang-3.4 and right to left
// for gcc-4.8.2
// but don't write any code relying on that: it would be highly unportable

#include <stdio.h>

int one() {
  printf("1\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 1;
}

int two() {
  printf("2\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 1;
}

int three() {
  printf("3\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 1;
}

void test(int a, int b, int c) {
  return;
}

int main() {
  test(one(), two(), three());
}
```